# elisp で、 window が縦分割か横分割かを判定したい

Tags: elisp

emacs で、今現在のフレームがウィンドウ分割されているとします。これが、縦分割か横分割かを判定したいです。

どのような elisp で実現できますか？

Comment: 横分割と縦分割が混在していない、という条件であれば、`(window-full-height-p)` の結果で判断できます(`nil` なら横分割、`t` なら縦分割)。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

（コメント転記）

横分割と縦分割が混在していない、という条件であれば、`(window-full-height-p)` の結果で判断できます(`nil` なら横分割、`t` なら縦分割)。